Let & Query to combine sorted count of frequency from two columns of data and format correctly before from TEXT JOIN
Data Location: Google Sheets with two columns where date/time in one and dollar values in the 2nd.
Goal is to group the entire dataset into specific ranges then identify the number of times of frequency for the last 7/14/30/60/90 days and output into a single cell formula.
Attempted to build helper columns to break the steps down further and was able to get the data into a final cell using =TEXT JOIN. Partially works but the data wasn't formatted correctly. As the parenthesis aren't going around the frequency count. That's problem 1.
Pushing forward I tried to use LET & QUERY to eliminate the helper columns and make into a single cell formula. Ultimately I'm a bit suck on this as when I push the formula into a single cell formula the only output I see is the number of days with no frequency count even though my previous steps worked when using helper cells.
Helper Sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t9Z-w3ytJD1om1YOVt-ylvuy75KEj0_wOupymE21HN0/
Question: How do I properly combine this into a single cell formula that will provide the correct output needed?
